# Crystal Report Sort the sum Value

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

Hi I'm using Crystal Report 2008 and my design is like this:

```
 Report header
 Page Header
 Group Header#1 (group by Customer) 
 Group Header#2 (group by Size) (S, M, L)
 Details
 Group Header#2 (group by Size) (S, M, L)
 Group Header#1 (group by Customer)
```

Because I want to get the Value by customer and by size so I put my summary fields in Group Header 2, so I have an output like this:

```
    Customer          Size          Amount
    ----------------------------------------
    CUS-A             SMALL          23500
    CUS-A             MEDIUM         33000
    CUS-B             SMALL          25500
    CUS-B             LARGE          22500
    CUS-C             SMALL          50500
    CUS-C             MEDIUM         20500
    CUS-C             LARGE          15500
```

The output is correct, but how can I sort the amount by descending order and the output should be like this:

```
Customer          Size          Amount
    ----------------------------------------
    CUS-C             SMALL          50500
    CUS-A             MEDIUM         33000
    CUS-B             SMALL          25500
    CUS-A             SMALL          23500
    CUS-B             LARGE          22500
    CUS-C             MEDIUM         20500
    CUS-C             LARGE          15500
```

Thanks,

Comment: Did you try sorting report by amount? http://www.btlynch.com/storage/devtc_crystal_sortgroups_10_suppress_filed.jpg?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1279641170119

Comment: i already tried the record and group sort expert but still not sort by highest to lowest value. it seems because the value are summarized by Customer and size.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you'll want to do is change your report to use a single group instead of two separate groups. Create a new formula that combines both the customer and size and use that instead: `{Table.Customer} + ' ' + {Table.Size}`

Now, go into the "Group Sort Expert" (under the "Report" menu). In the "For this group sort" drop-down menu, select "All", based on "Sum of {Table.Amount}". (Note that this is assuming the group amount summation is already in your report. If it isn't, you'll need to add it.) Finally, select the "Descending" radio button.